# how to launch an ipad app when a text box is selected

Tags: ios, ipad, barcode-scanner

Ideally what I'd like to do is add a shortcut to the iPad keyboard that launches another program and in my case a scanning application.

We'd like to utilize the iPad camera as a scanner and whenever we tap a text input box in any third party application, have the ability to launch the scanner software, scan the code and place the scanned data into the text box.

I've read about the scanning libraries and using actual barcode scanners, but I haven't seen anything that would allow you to create this type of shortcut.

Any thoughts or suggestions on where I may find more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**: It is not possible.

## Answer

The iPhone keyboard is cannot be modified system-wide or replaced. See the 4th question on the [Fleksy FAQ](http://fleksy.com/#faq)
As you mentioned, your options are:

1. using a scanning library
2. using a barcode scanner

### Scanning Library

If you don't have access to the application source or can't convince the developer to add scanner support, your only option here would be to use a stand alone scanner app, switching between apps to copy-paste the scanned data into the text field.

**Pros**

- Free (ZXing, zbar, etc)

**Cons**

- Slow. The camera scanner takes about a second, plus the time it takes to switch apps and copy paste. You are looking at ~10 seconds

### Barcode Scanner

It is possible to integrate a barcode scanner into an app using the provided SDK and that is advisable for most applications, but a lot of scanners also support HID mode. In HID mode, the scanner connects to iOS (or Android) as a keyboard and can "type" into the active input field.

**Pros**

- Fast, very fast
- Use in HID mode to scan data directly into text input without modifications to the app

**Cons**

- Expensive

**Disclaimer** I work for Socket Mobile. Socket Mobile makes beautiful bluetooth barcode scanners.

Comment: The iOS keyboard has had the properties inputView and inputAccessoryView since iOS 3.2. Both provide functionality for some level of customization.

Comment: Both of those are application level customizations. The question was about adding functionality to a *3rd-party* application. It is not possible to customize the keyboard system-wide.

Comment: I had assumed he wanted to customize the keyboard on an application of his own. I re-read now. Thanks for calling it out.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information. All the responses were very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Long things short: if you want to add that button in the keyboard to every app it's not possible then (on non-jailbroken devices at least go to the end for more on that).

You can have your own app for scanning though and make it so it's really easy to copy the code to the clipboard area so you can jump to the first app and paste it on the text field.

That or you develop a tool for jailbroken devices if you don't need to put the app through Apple approval process i.e. a in-house solution.